# Using QMAKE to build a both 32 and 64 bits versions of project

Tags: qt, 32bit-64bit, qmake

I need to generate a 32 bits version of my application however I am compiling on a 64 bits OS. I'm looking for a way to make QMake to generate both 32 and 64 bits versions of my application. If this is not possible I would like to know how to switch to 32 bits.
I would also like to avoid having to mess with the generated makefile.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a construction something like:

```
CONFIG += 32bit

CONFIG(32bit) {
    TARGET = 32bit_binary
    QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -m32
    LIBS += -L<path to 32bit libraries>
}
CONFIG(64bit) {
    TARGET = 64bit_binary
}
```

in your .pro file. Then you only need to change  one line to recompile for the other architecture.

Comment: You didn't mention which compiler you are using: you will need to change the flags in my example to the right ones for your compiler.

Comment: I'm using GCC so I believe '-m32' is correct but for some reason the qmake generates the makefile with '-m64' anyway

Comment: Sorry the variale should be QMAKE_CXXFLAGS and not QMAKE_CFLAGS_RELEASE. I've edited my answer

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This is going straight to my cheat list.

Answer (score 2):

Make use of `win32:` in front of each command you would like be run for win32 architecture only. Or can use a scope as

```
win32 {
     SOURCES += paintwidget_win.cpp
 }
```

Also, you may refer to the architecture win32 or x64 with the ($Platform) MSDN macro for Visual Studio.