# force 32 bits program in .pro file

Tags: c++, qt-creator, qmake

I know I can run qmake from the command line and use:

```
-spec linux-g++-32
```

From the .pro file i've tried to add alternatively "-m32" or "-32" to "CFLAGS" or "QMAKE_CXXFLAGS" but it does not work.

```
CFLAGS += -m32
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -m32
```

What shall I do then ?

**EDIT:**

this is what is produced with the above flag...

```
g++ -c -pipe -m32 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I. -o fxa_march.o ../fxa_march/fxa_march.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -m32 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I. -o reports.o ../fxa_march/reports.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -m32 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I. -o fxa_march_params.o ../fxa_march/fxa_march_params.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -m32 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I. -o reportgroup.o ../fxa_march/reportgroup.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -m32 -g -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_XMLPATTERNS_LIB -DQT_XML_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I. -o db_wrapper.o ../fxa_march/db_wrapper.cpp
../fxa_march/db_wrapper.cpp: In function 'std::string as_string(FX::dbvalue, FX::dbtype)':
../fxa_march/db_wrapper.cpp:17: warning: enumeration value 'dbtype_dbvoid' not handled in switch
../fxa_march/db_wrapper.cpp:17: warning: enumeration value 'dbtype_dbdate' not handled in switch
../fxa_march/db_wrapper.cpp:17: warning: enumeration value 'dbtype_dbmoney' not handled in switch
g++ -Wl,-rpath,/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/lib -o fxa_march fxa_march.o reports.o fxa_march_params.o reportgroup.o db_wrapper.o    -L/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/lib -L../../../fx/libfx -lfx -L../../../fx/MQLib -lMQ -L/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_bin/lib -lboost_timer -lboost_system -lboost_chrono -lboost_regex -L/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/lib -lxerces-c -lQtXmlPatterns -L/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/lib -lQtNetwork -lQtXml -lQtCore -lpthread
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible ../../../fx/libfx/libfx.so when searching for -lfx
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lfx
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [fxa_march] Error 1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using QMAKE to build a both 32 and 64 bits versions of project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383475/using-qmake-to-build-a-both-32-and-64-bits-versions-of-project)

Comment: What is the problem? That the spec isn't adding the `-m32` options automatically, or the linker error?

Comment: the linker error was the problem.

Comment: @phresnel , This is not duplicate. Because the flag -m32 is not enough, I needed to link to 32 bits libraries. I simply discovered that in the project settings of Qt creator, I could put the "-spec linux-g++-32" option as in the command line and it solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here is the point:

the diff between the generated makefile ( through QtCreator ) and the one generated by my command line is:

```
INCPATH       = -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++-32 -I. -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I.
```

Vs

```
INCPATH       = -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I../fxa_march -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtCore -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXml -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include/QtXmlPatterns -I/Soft/fox_dev/Qt-4.7.4/include -I../../../fx/libfx -I../../../fx/MQLib -I/Soft/fox_dev/boost/boost_1_54_0 -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I/Soft/fox_dev/xerces-c-3.1.1-x86-linux-gcc-3.4/include -I. -I../fxa_march -I.
```

however one can go to "Project-> Build Settings -> [choose configuration to modify] -> And edit the "Qmake step" with additionnal argument:

```
-spec linux-g++-32
```

you will also need to add in the .pro file either of:

```
CFLAGS += -m32
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -m32
```

Answer (score 0):

In .pro file, try writting all commands inside a scope prefixed by `win32`

```
win32 {
     SOURCES += paintwidget_win.cpp
     # ...
 }
```

Commands inside the scope will be run only if the win32 variable is set.

Comment: Thanks, I'm on linux, but indeed, I should do similar things