# Error with OpenCV in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I have problem with including a OpenCV library to Qt Creator.

**Here my code:**

```
INCLUDEPATH += "C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/include" \

CONFIG(debug,debug|release) {



LIBS += -L"C:/OpenCV/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib" \
    -lopencv_core2413d \
    -lopencv_calib3d2413d \
    -lopencv_contrib2413d \
    -lopencv_features2d2413d \
    -lopencv_flann2413d \
    -lopencv_gpu2413d \
    -lopencv_highgui2413d \
    -lopencv_imgproc2413d \
    -lopencv_videostab2413d
}

CONFIG(debug,debug|release) {
    DEFINES += QT_NO_WARNING_OUTPUT QT_NO_DEBUG_OUTPUT
    LIBS +=  -L"C:/OptiNavCV/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib" \
    -lopencv_core2413 \
    -lopencv_calib3d2413 \
    -lopencv_contrib2413 \
    -lopencv_features2d2413 \
    -lopencv_flann2413 \
    -lopencv_gpu2413 \
    -lopencv_highgui2413 \
    -lopencv_imgproc2413 \
    -lopencv_videostab2413
    }
}
```

**Error:**
C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe -f Makefile.Release
    cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2 -MD -Zc:strictStrings -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -EHsc -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_WIDGETS_LIB -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DNDEBUG -I..\TestAppQt -I. -I........\OptiNavCV\opencv\build\include -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtWidgets -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtGui -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtANGLE -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I. -I........\Qt\Qt5.5.1\5.5\msvc2013_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Forelease\ @C:\Users\szymo\AppData\Local\Temp\mainwindow.obj.11752.15.jom
mainwindow.cpp
    link /NOLOGO /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /INCREMENTAL:NO /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS "/MANIFESTDEPENDENCY:type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*' processorArchitecture='*'" /MANIFEST:embed /OUT:release\TestAppQt.exe @C:\Users\szymo\AppData\Local\Temp\TestAppQt.exe.11752.1422.jom
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)" (?fastFree@cv@@YAXPEAX@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: __cdecl cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(class cv::Mat const &)" (??0_InputArray@cv@@QEAA@AEBVMat@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __cdecl cv::Mat::deallocate(void)" (?deallocate@Mat@cv@@QEAAXXZ) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "int __cdecl cv::_interlockedExchangeAdd(int *,int)" (?_interlockedExchangeAdd@cv@@YAHPEAHH@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::imshow(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,class cv::_InputArray const &)" (?imshow@cv@@YAXAEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@AEBV_InputArray@1@@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
mainwindow.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class cv::Mat __cdecl cv::imread(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int)" (?imread@cv@@YA?AVMat@1@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@H@Z) referenced in function "public: __cdecl MainWindow::MainWindow(class QWidget *)" (??0MainWindow@@QEAA@PEAVQWidget@@@Z)
release\TestAppQt.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 6 unresolved externals
jom: C:\Users\szymo\Documents\build-TestAppQt-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Release\Makefile.Release [release\TestAppQt.exe] Error 1120
jom: C:\Users\szymo\Documents\build-TestAppQt-Desktop_Qt_5_5_1_MSVC2013_64bit-Release\Makefile [release] Error 2
09:52:59: The process "C:\Qt\Qt5.5.1\Tools\QtCreator\bin\jom.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project TestAppQt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
When executing step "Make"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to link 32-bit library (opencv_core)

```
-L"C:/OptiNavCV/opencv/build/x86/vc12/lib" \
```

...

```
LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl cv::fastFree(void *)"
```

to x64 project

```
TestAppQt (kit: Desktop Qt 5.5.1 MSVC2013 64bit)
```

Comment: How I can change it?

Comment: Look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383475/using-qmake-to-build-a-both-32-and-64-bits-versions-of-project